# Does Firebird 3.0 run on OS X?

Tags: macos, firebird

Does anyone know whether FB 3.0 runs on OS X and if so, where I can find files to download?  I only need the client, as I need to connect to a FB server running on Windows Server.

Comment: *"MacOS X and other platforms will follow"* – http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/news/firebird-3-0-is-released/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there does not appear to be an OS X version at this moment, but this information is temporary and will be outdated someday, hence is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Yes, Firebird 3 can run on MacOS X, but no there is no installer right now. Paul Beach who maintains the MacOS X port + installer is still working on a number of issues, see also https://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/mailman/message/35398306/